# Switch statement default range?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case, default

This is the last portion of my assignment specs that I cannot figure out:

> Uses the default case to 'catch' a large range of grades.
>   Do not list every number from 0 to 59 as a separate case!

This is my code and my default needs to consider the values between 0 and 59 using the instructions above.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

```
double percentage;
int grade;

cout << "Enter your grade percentage " <<endl;
cin >> percentage;

if (percentage < 0 || percentage > 100 )
    cout << "Invalid entry " << endl;

grade = (int)round(percentage);

cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

switch(grade)

{
    case 100:
    case 99:
    case 98:
    case 97:
    case 96:
    case 95:
    case 94:
    case 93:
    case 92:
    case 91:
    case 90:
        cout << "Percentage: " << percentage << "% " << "Grade: A " << "Points: 4.00"; 
        break;
    case 89:
    case 88:
    case 87:
    case 86:
    case 85:
    case 84:
    case 83:
    case 82:
    case 81:
    case 80:
        cout << "Percentage: " << percentage << "% " << "Grade: B " << "Points: 3.00";
        break;
    case 79:
    case 78:
    case 77:
    case 76:
    case 75:
    case 74:
    case 73:
    case 72:
    case 71:
    case 70:
        cout << "Percentage: " << percentage << "% " << "Grade: C " << "Points: 2.00";
        break;
    case 69:
    case 68:
    case 67:
    case 66:
    case 65:
    case 64:
    case 63:
    case 62:
    case 61:
    case 60:
        cout << "Percentage: " << percentage << "% " << "Grade: D " << "Points: 1.00";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Percentage: " << percentage << "% " << "Grade: F " << "Points: 0.00";
        break;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: this is in C++ obviously

Comment: You can edit your questions, to retag them...correct problems in formatting, or respond to requests for clarification.  *(But don't edit to make it into a new question... ask a new one...!)*  But more importantly, what can't you figure out?  What input are you giving it, what output are you getting that confuses you?

Comment: So the default must work fine right?

Comment: An `if` statement would be more readable IMHO

Comment: If you took programming in school, you should know that ``if statements are for ranges and switch statements are for conditions``. That's what I was taught anyway, not sure why your instructor would expect a switch statement for this.

Comment: @ub3rst4r: Hmm? `if` statements are for conditions (`if (condition) statement`). `switch` statements are for selecting from a set of values.

Comment: Hint: once you normalized `grade` to be in `[0, 100]` think what values `grade / 10` can take, and how they relate back to `grade` ranges.

Comment: A few things: 1) yes, your implementation seems to do what the instructor is asking.  They just want you to use `default` to handle all other cases, and you do.  2) This way is ugly.  @dxiv's suggestion is much much cleaner and still uses default in the way the instructor wants.  3) Unfortunately, this question boils down to: "What is my instructor asking me to do?  Did I do it right?" and that strikes me as extremely specific to you (and your class) only.  As such, I'm going to vote to close it for that purpose.

Comment: First, you could divide the grade by 10, that would also divide your cases by 10. Except for that, if you excluded anything out of the [0,100] range the default case can catch all the remaining values. Though it might be fun as an educational challenge, I would never use that in real code. Much too messy and a pain to maintain, for no gain in terms of code size or execution speed, which are the usual reasons why you might want to write obfuscated code...

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the help.  The real problem I am having is whenever I enter a # that is less than 0 or greater than 100 the if cout is printed as well as the default cout.  I only want the if cout to be printed in this situation.  Any suggestions?

Comment: put an `else` after the range check and Bob should be your uncle :)

Comment: wow i cant believe i missed that lol!!! thanks man

Comment: thanks to everyone for the help i think i have this figured out

Comment: "*The real problem I am having is ...*" -- If that's the real problem, you need to ask about it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Going along with @dvix's comment, if you know that grades will be between 0 and 100 inclusive, you can shorten your code in the following way:

```
switch( grade/10 ) {

    case 10:
    case 9:
        ... Do something ...
        break;
    case 8:
    case 7:
        ... Do something else...
        break
   ....

}
```

and use default at the end, saving a couple cases.

Having said that, `if` is probably the idiomatic way to handle this normally.